# Kotlin Fuel REST Client Proxy error

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to create an Android App with Kotlin using Fuel Rest Client but I get the following error in my Logcat:
E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!
... and ...
getaddrinfo: dev-worktable.pl get result from proxy gai_error = 11

Here is my MainActivity.kt ...

```
package com.corcode.myapplication

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.httpGet
import com.github.kittinunf.result.Result
import com.github.kittinunf.result.getAs

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val URL: String = "http://dev-worktable.pl/api/offers/list"

    URL.httpGet().responseString { request, response, result ->
        //do something with response
        when (result) {
            is Result.Failure -> {}
            is Result.Success -> {
                println("Result: ${result.get()}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... and dependencies in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0'
compile 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel:1.9.0' //for JVM
compile 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-android:1.9.0' //for Android
compile 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-rxjava:1.9.0' //for RxJava support
compile 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-livedata:1.9.0' //for LiveData support
compile 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-gson:1.9.0' //for Gson support
}
```

Comment: What happens if you extract the `httpGet` call, and test it, instead of wedging it inside the handler function?

Comment: Same, nothing changed

Comment: I don't believe that if you separate the `GET` call you have the same problem, because I did, and had a different issue. See this [issue](https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel/issues/212).

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace please? Also, I can't reproduce this, even with your exact same code. So if you are no longer having this issue, it was due to the webserver you were trying to call

Comment: It works now see [this](https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel/issues/212#issuecomment-322981634)